Global dark mode theme switcher for AG Grid
I am using ag-grid in a Remix app that uses Tailwind CSS. The app has a global dark mode switcher.
Ag-grid has dark and light css classes available. (There is also an 'auto' class but that seems to be controlled only by prefers-color-scheme and so is not affected by my global dark mode toggle.)
I want ag-grid to use the ag-theme-quartz class in light mode and ag-theme-quartz-dark in dark mode but I am having difficulty. I tried finding the theme using const { mode } = useThemeMode(); where useThemeMode is from the flowbite tailwind theme switcher component I am using and then setting the ag-grid class using
className={mode === "dark" ? "ag-theme-quartz-dark" : "ag-theme-quartz"}

but Remix is a server side rendered framework and the server does not know what colour mode the client has chosen so this gives SSR errors.
When I am styling my own components I use tailwind's dark: prefix but it does not seem possible to use this with non tailwind classes.
How can I make ag-grid's class match my theme?
